# Why does a call to the crypt() function from unistd.h set the errno to ENOENT?

Tags: c++, c, crypt, unistd.h

I have written and run the following code:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "errno = " << errno << std::endl;
  std::cout << crypt("sometext", "ab") << std::endl;
  std::cout << "errno = " << errno <<std:: endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The initial value of `errno` was `0`, but after a call to the `crypt()` function it was set to `2` (**ENOENT**).

Here is the output:

```
errno = 0
abtAunjzvWWRQ
errno = 2
```

Comment: The crypt library probably tried to open some kind of resource file somewhere along the way, which failed, but the crypt library didn't consider that a problem.  (Perhaps it had a Plan B.)  See also [question 12.24](http://c-faq.com/stdio/printferrno.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: The man page of `crypt` does not mention anywhere anything about setting `errno`, it just says *On success, a pointer to the encrypted password is returned.  On error, NULL is returned.*. In your case it doesn't return `NULL`, so the function ended successfully. `errno` must be set somewhere inside `crypt` and the function knows how to handle the error (note that a function does not have to manually set `errno` to 0).

Comment: This is pretty common, and it's why setting `errno` to 0, calling a function, and then checking `errno` is *not* a recommended thing to do.  It's generally only meaningful to inspect `errno` after a library function has indicated via its return value that it has failed -- and then only if it's a library function that's documented as setting `errno`.

Comment: Although, not the root cause of in this case, any of the stream operations that are occurring within the the `cout` statements could easily change the value of `errno`....

Comment: There is no evidence here that `crypt()` did it, as it is interleaved with streams I/O; and no reason why any of this code should not disturb `errno`. Examining it is only valid when the immediately prior system call has returned -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the C standard says about `errno` (§7.5, para 3, emphasis added.)

> The value of `errno` in the initial thread is zero at program startup
>   (the initial value of `errno` in other threads is an indeterminate
>   value), but is never set to zero by any library function. **The value
>   of `errno` may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or
>   not there is an error**, provided the use of `errno` is not documented
>   in the description of the function in this International Standard.

And here's (part of) what [Posix says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html) (again, emphasis added):

The value of `errno` should only be examined when it is indicated to be valid by a function's return value.… No function in this volume of POSIX.1-2008 shall set `errno` to 0. **The setting of `errno` after a successful call to a function is unspecified** unless the description of that function specifies that `errno` shall not be modified.

`crypt` is a Posix function (as indicated by its presence in `unistd.h`). The description does not specify that `errno` shall not be modified. So it may be and it was.

In short, *never* attempt to use the value of `errno` unless a function has clearly reported an error and that function is documented to set `errno`. And in that case, make sure you use it (or save its value) immediately after the call to that function, and before doing anything else which might set `errno` (which includes the use of `iostreams` and `cstdio`).

That might all seem a bit odd in isolation, but it actually makes perfect sense. Consider, for example, a function which needs to consult a configuration file, if one exists. It's going to include code something like:

```
FILE* config = fopen(configFileName, "r");
if (config) { /* Read the file */ }
else { /* Set default values */ }
```

If the config file doesn't exist, it simply doesn't get used. No problem. But `errno` may well have been set by the `fopen` failure.

This sort of thing is pretty common in library functions, which perform initialization on the first call. If it weren't for this provision, any library function which called another library function would have to carefully save `errno` before it started and then restore it at the end, unless an actual error was being reported. I'll bet your functions don't do that :) -- mine certainly don't. It's fiddly and error-prone. Better and more auditable is the convention actually adopted: `errno` is only valid if the function definitely reported an error.