# Errno does not recognize all files

Tags: c, file-io, directory

I am working on writing a program which when passed a directory it is able to run through every subdirectory & file in those subdirectories. It works fine when the commented out condition is active, but when that portion is removed, line two will return `errno == 2` in some cases when the file actually exists, and `errno == 20` only for some other files.  How can I fix this so that it can recognize every file without the commented out portion of the condition?

```
node* directories(char* fileName, node* result){
    DIR *din = opendir(fileName);
    char currdirec[9999];
    if(errno == 20) //&& fileName[strlen(fileName)-4] == '.')
    {
        node* list = createList(fileName);
        head = NULL;
        head = mergeLists(result, list);
    }
    else
    {
        struct dirent *dir;
        getcwd(currdirec, sizeof(currdirec));
        char* temp = currdirec;
        strcat(currdirec, "/");
        strcat(currdirec, fileName);
        chdir(currdirec);
        while((dir = readdir(din)) != NULL)
        {
            if(dir->d_type == DT_REG)
            {
                directories(dir->d_name, result);
            }       
            else if(dir->d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0)
            {
                directories(dir->d_name, result);
                chdir(currdirec);           
            }
        }
        chdir(temp);
    }                            
    return result;
}
```

`fileName` is directory or file from command line.

Comment: when asking about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem so we can debug it.  The posted code is (mostly) useless for answering your question.

Comment: amongst other problems with the posted code, what header files are being included?  what is the definition of `node`?  What is the definition of `head`?

Comment: under linux, the errno value of 20 is named: ENOTDIR, meaning Not a directory.  So why is the code calling `createList()` and `mergeList()`  for something that is not a directory?  Suggest just checking the returned value from `opendir()`  and IF it was successful, the checking that the directory name was a directory (or not) and if a directory if the name matches `,` or `..` to ignore it.

Comment: regarding: `getcwd(currdirec, sizeof(currdirec));
                char* temp = currdirec;
                strcat(currdirec, "/");
                strcat(currdirec, fileName);
                
                chdir(currdirec);`  The execution is ALREADY in the current directory, so what is the call to `chdir()` expected to accomplish?

Comment: regarding: `if(dir->d_type == DT_REG)`  This is checking of the current entry is a regular file, not a directory, so why be recursing into the `directories()` function?

Comment: @user3629249 last time I posted the full code I got flamed for it being too long

Comment: Oh... see here is the problem.... the part where I explained literally all of this was deleted by Foggzie, which is causing confusion.  The purpose of this code is to create a full list of every single word in every single text file in a directory and its sub directories

Comment: @JoeCur Posting full code without trimming out those part that are not part of the problem will get you comments because then the code is not Minimal. Posting part of your code without including everything needed for us to be able to copy-paste-safe-compile-test will get you comments because then the code is not Complete and Verifiable. I'm guessing that Foggzie deleted that part of your explanation because what you do with the files *after* your code finds them is not part of your problem. Your problem is *finding* all the files.

Comment: @JoeCur ... therefore, for example deleting the `node *list  = createList(` ... `mergeLists(` ... `);` lines and replacing them with a `printf("File found: %s\n", fileName);` would have made your code more Minimal *and* Complete at the same time.

Comment: Despite such complicated replies the answer was to reset errno = 0 in the if(errno == 20) condition

Answer (score 3):

You must not check the value of `errno` before you have checked that an error occurred. (In this case, `opendir` would return `NULL` to indicate an error.) If no error was reported, `errno` may have any value, so it is very likely your test will be a false positive.

See [Why does a call to the crypt() function from unistd.h set the errno to ENOENT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341043/why-does-a-call-to-the-crypt-function-from-unistd-h-set-the-errno-to-enoent/49342339#49342339) for some more details.